# Instantiated object doesn't instantiate other object on the raycast

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, instantiation, raycasting

When the code starts I instantiate a Random amount of new raycasts (from 1 to 4) from the original Raycast:

```
public class MultipleRaycasts : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Raycastobj;
private GameObject RCclone;
public int RandomSTRUNKnumber;

 void Start()
 {
    Destroy(gameObject);
    RandomSTRUNKnumber = Random.Range(1, 4);
    for (int m = 0; m < RandomSTRUNKnumber; m++)
    { 
        RCclone = Instantiate(Raycastobj);
    }
 }
}
```

After the button is clicked all the moving raycasts are stopping if they hit the object (I am not attaching this one), and instantiate the "RandomSTrunk" object on the other object:

```
public class PlayerRayINST : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform RandomSTrunk2;
public bool RCnn;
public bool RCCheck;
public void Update()
{
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 100f, Color.yellow);
    RCnn = true;
    RCCheck = true;
    Ray ray1 = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    RaycastHit hit1;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray1, out hit1))
    {
        if (hit1.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SelectableTrunk>())
        {
            RCnn = false;
            RCCheck = false;
        }
        else
        {
            RCnn = true;
            RCCheck = true;
        }
    }
}
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    Invoke("Addbranch", 0.5f);
}
void Addbranch()
{
    Ray ray2 = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    RaycastHit hit2;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray2, out hit2))
    {
        if (hit2.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SelectableTrunk>())
        {
            Transform clone = Instantiate(RandomSTrunk2);
            clone.position = hit2.point;
            clone.LookAt(hit2.transform.position - hit2.transform.forward, hit2.normal);
        }
    }
}
}
```

My code somehow instantiates the "RandomSTrunk" only from the original Raycast. It ignores the instantiated earlier Raycasts and does not want to Instantiate the "RandomSTrunk" from the other raycasts.

However, if I put `Update` instead of `OnMouseDown` It will instantiate correctly but with millions of generated clones. I've just started learning unity, so please help me ;)

Comment: `OnMouseDown()` means mouse clicking that object. So say there's a button and 50 rays, you clicked on the button, it triggers the button's `OnMouseDown()` but not the rays' `OnMouseDown()`s. One way might be checking the mouse state in `Update()` every once in a while.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang got it! And how to do it? Would you mind writing a code? ;)